# Can we make the ADF JSON mapping in COPY Activity Case-insensitive?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

So, actually I'm using the ADF Copy Activity to load the CSV files from the azure blob storage to snowflake table. And column mapping is done using the json with source and sink column name as below:

```
{ "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "first_name",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "FIRST_NAME",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Address",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "ADDRESS",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }
```

my csv file will come with the two column **first_name** and **Address** but the problem here is that I can receive the column name in any case like **FIRST_NamE** or **address**.

So is there any way to make this column mapping case-insensitive?

Comment: Do you have access to data flows?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham, Yes I do have the access to the dataflow, but in our requirements, we don't want to use the dataflow as it requires several minutes to activate the cluster, so we are avoiding dataflow for now

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by making the mapping case-insensitive?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham my csv file will come with the two columns "first_name" and "Address" but the problem here is that I can receive the column name in any case like "FIRST_NamE" or "address". But in json mapping I have already mentioned the "first_name" and "Address", so incase If I receive the file with the column "FIRST_NAME" ADF copy activity will fail

Comment: How do you want to map these inconsistent names to sink? Is it all upper case or something else?

Comment: yes I want it in all upper case, even I receive column as "first_name" this should be mapped to the "FIRST_NAME" so that it will be consistent all the time

Answer (score 1):

You can build the mapping dynamically and then with the help of `toUpper()` function, you can convert the column name to uppercase.

The mapping format would be same as given in the question which I have built dynamically using:

- Get Metadata activity to get the header as single value as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Set variable activity to build the required map.

[image]

- For each to create an array of each column map.

[image]

- The last set variable activity to create the final mapping.

[image]

- Finally, copy data activity to with desired mapping as dynamic content.

[image]

The result would be as shown below:

[image]

The following are the pipeline JSON for:

Pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "get comma seperated header",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "mapping",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@split(activity('get comma seperated header').output.firstRow['Prop_0'],',')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "map",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "maps",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "{\"source\": {\"name\": \"@{item()}\",\"type\": \"String\"},\"sink\": {\"name\": \"@{toUpper(item())}\",\"type\": \"String\"}}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "mapping",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "get comma seperated header",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "map",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "{\"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "final",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@concat(variables('map'),'\"mappings\": [',join(variables('maps'),','),']}')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "final",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "value": "@json(variables('final'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "src",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "map": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "maps": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "final": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- Get Metadata source dataset JSON:

```
{
    "name": "csv1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "adls",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": "input.csv",
                "fileSystem": "data"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": "|",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": false,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "FiRsT_NaME",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Address",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I have used csv as sink for demonstration.